# Solve the congruence in number theory

Tags: number-theory, congruences

I'm confused how to solve this. $x^2 \equiv$ 11 (mod 35).

I know you're to split it up into $x^2 \equiv$11 (mod 7) and $x^2 \equiv$ 11 (mod 5). This produces answers of $x^2 \equiv$ 1, 4 (mod 5) and $\equiv$ 2, 5 (mod 7).

What I don't get is the next line: $x\equiv a$(7)(3) + $b$(5)(3).

Where does the 3 come from? Out of thin air? Thanks.

Comment: From $x\equiv\pm 1\pmod 5$ and $x\equiv\pm 2\pmod 7$, the author invokes the Chinese Remainder Theorem (since $\gcd(5,7)=1$ and noting that $3$ is the multiplicative inverse of $5,7$ modulo $7,5$ respectively) to get the solution as $x\equiv (\pm 1)(7)(3)+(\pm 2)(5)(3)\pmod{35}$

Comment: Another approach would be to note that $11\equiv 81\equiv 9^2\pmod{35}$ to get $x\equiv\pm 9\pmod{35}$ or $x\equiv\pm 9\pmod{(5,7),(7,5)~\textrm{resp.}}$

Answer (score 1):

Some people apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem as stated, but I find that unwieldy in many cases. You have four pairs of congruences to solve; I'll show you a good technique with one of them.

We want $x\equiv 4\pmod 5$, and $x\equiv 5\pmod 7$. We'll start with the first one: The number $4$ is congruent to $4$ modulo $5$, and adding any multiple of $5$ to it doesn't change that. Thus, we start adding multiples of $5$, and stop when we reach a number that satisfies the second congruence: $4, 9, 14, 19$. There, we found it. The number $19$ satisfies both congruences, and that's one solution, modulo $35$. You can find the other three in a similar manner.

If you had a third congruence to satisfy, you could take $19$, and if it wasn't the solution, start adding multiples of $35$ until you get the needed number.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$3\equiv 7^{-1}\mod 5$$ and $$3\equiv 5^{-1}\mod 7$$

Therefore we have to multiply both residues with $3$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't follow.

Comment: @HamSandwich: It's just a direct application of CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm sorry.